# How To Cache Images in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, dom

Suppose I have a list of url's like so :

`[ '/images/1', '/images/2', ... ]`

And I want to prefetch `n` of those so that transitioning between images is faster. What I am doing now in `componentWillMount` is the following:

```
componentWillMount() {
      const { props } = this;
      const { prefetchLimit = 1, document = dummyDocument, imgNodes } = props;
      const { images } = document;
      const toPrefecth = take(prefetchLimit, images);
      const merged = zip(toPrefecth, imgNodes);

      merged.forEach(([url, node]) => {
        node.src = url;
      });
    }
```

with `imgNodes` being defined like so:

`imgNodes: times(_ => new window.Image(), props.prefetchLimit),`

and `times`, `zip`, and `take` coming from [ramda](http://ramdajs.com).

Now when I use those urls inside of react like so:

`<img src={url} />`

it hits the browser cache according to the `Etag` and `Expire` tags regardless of where the url is used. I also plan on using this to prefetch the next `n` images whenever we hit `n - 1` inside of the view, reusing `imgNodes` in the same manner.

My question are:

- Is this even a valid idea give 100+ components that will use this idea but only 1 will be visible at a time?
- Will I run into memory issues by doing this? I am assuming that `imgNodes` will be garbage collected when the component is unmounted.

We are using `redux` so I could save these images in the store but that seems like I am handling the caching instead of leveraging the browser's natural cache.

How bad of an idea is this?

Comment: Did you go anywhere with this? I'm interested...

Comment: @MathieuK. We have basically the same structure/interface as described above, leveraging normal HTTP caching.

Comment: So you rely on the default behavior of browsers/HTTP ?

Comment: I'm relying on the way that I understand the `img` spec for HTML. It sounds like it says once you ask a browser to fetch a resource, if you ask again and it is inside of your list of known images, that it will not have to re-ask for that resource. https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-img-element.html#list-of-available-images

I am hoping that if I am misunderstanding that, that the browser/HTTP cache will say don't refetch.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't need to do it in all of your components. As soon as an image is downloaded it gets cached by the browser and will be accessible in all components, so you can do this only once somewhere in a high-level component.

I don't know what exactly UX you are trying to create by caching images, however, your code only initiates downloading images but doesn't know whether an image is being downloaded, has been downloaded successfully or even failed. So, for example, you want to show a button to change images or add a class to a component only when the images have been downloaded (to make it smooth), your current code may let you down.

You may want to resolve this with Promises.

```
// create an utility function somewhere
const checkImage = path =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const img = new Image()
        img.onload = () => resolve(path)
        img.onerror = () => reject()

        img.src = path
    })

...

// then in your component
class YourComponent extends Component {

    this.state = { imagesLoaded: false }

    componentDidMount = () =>
        Promise.all(
            R.take(limit, imgUrls).map(checkImage)
        ).then(() => this.setState(() => ({ imagesLoaded: true })),
               () => console.error('could not load images'))

    render = () =>
        this.state.imagesLoaded
            ? <BeautifulComponent />
            : <Skeleton />
}
```

Regarding memory consumption — I don't think anything bad will happen. Browsers normally limit the number of parallel xhr requests, so you won't be able to create a gigantic heap usage spike to crash anything, as unused images will garbage collected (yet, preserved in browser cache).

Redux store is a place to store the app state, not the app assets, but anyway you won't be able to store any actual images there.

Comment: you are missing reject param in calling constructor for new Promise(checkImage  function) ?

Comment: yeah, indeed — fixed

Answer (score 0):

This is simple and works fine:

```
//arraySrcs=["myImage1.png","myImage2.jpg", "myImage3.jpg", etc]

{arraySrcs.map((e) => (
    <img src={e} style={{ display: "none" }} />
  ))}
```

Comment: Tomerikoo why are the emoji, the bold letter and the link edited?

Comment: I guess because this was using styling and icons to get attention (instead of to add value to the answer), and the link also doesn't add any value to the answer, and basically is just advertising for something unrelated.