# React JS, How to perform image caching

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Carousel where the images changes in every 3 seconds.  Whenever the image changes it calls the back end for image and it may overload server in production.

Should I go for image storing in localStorage and retrieve it ?

```
//storing image index
const [imageIndex, setImageIndex] = React.useState(0);

//below are the images I change
 const images = useMemo(
    () => [
      "/media/images/banner1.jpg",
      "/media/images/banner2.jpg",
      "/media/images/banner3.jpg",
    ],
    []
  );

//function to change image index (0-2)
  const nextImage = () => {
    setImageIndex((prev) => (prev + 1) % images.length);
    setTimeout(nextImage, 2000);
  };

  React.useEffect(nextImage, []);

  return (
    <div>
      
            <img
              src={images[imageIndex]}
              alt={images[imageIndex]}
              style={{ width: "100%" }}
            />
            
    </div>
  );
}

export default Carousal;
```

Below question seems to have answer for me but I did not get the idea in my case.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48480983/10515390

[image]

Comment: memoize your images array with `useMemo` or move them outside of component

Comment: I will look into useMemo,Thanks

Comment: Do you actually _see_ that image is not cached locally? Browser should do this for you, after the first time then it won't (shouldn't) be downloaded again.

Comment: I have enabled cache and it stop repeated server query . What shall do If user had disabled the cache ?

Comment: Nothing, it shouldn't be your concern. No users disable the cache (only devs when testing performance and load time). If you REALLY want to (because you want to avoid flashing content/layout when switching to a new image with a low bandwidth connection) then you download them (`images.map(x => <img href={x} />)`) but you make them invisible (`display: none`) and _unhide_ the visible one. Check what browsers will actually do: they might be smart enough to avoid downloading an invisible image (in that case you could move the offscreen with `transform` or make them transparent with `opacity`)

Comment: "if the user has disabled the cash " **the images acquired will need to be cached before rendered. The session images will stay cashed regardless - The cash will only be cleared on refresh.**