# webpack 5: magic comments not working for images

Tags: reactjs, webpack, lazy-loading

I am trying to preload/prefetch an image so that I don't have to be connected to the internet at the exact moment to display the image. It's for a "you are offline" page in my app.

My app is written in React and I am using webpack for my bundler.

I was reading online that the webpack magic comments feature might be able to do that.
https://medium.com/webpack/link-rel-prefetch-preload-in-webpack-51a52358f84c

It's not working for me.

The image that I am trying to preload/prefetch does not show and there is no `<link rel` tag added to the DOM.

Checkout the demo repository here:
https://github.com/aubreyquinn/preload-webpack-demo/tree/main

package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `useState` hook to trigger the `re-render`, The webpack prefetching is working fine but react is not re-rendering since it is unaware of such loading.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Flowers from "../assets/flowers.jpg";


// Home component
const Home = () => {
    const [lilies, setLilies] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        import(/* webpackPrefetch: true */ "../assets/lilies.jpg").then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
            setLilies(res.default);
        });
    }, []);
    return (
        <>
            <div>React Application</div>
            <img src={Flowers} height={200} />
            <img src={lilies} height={200} />
        </>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

Try the above code out, it's working just fine.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work when offline though. I still have a network request in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't need to preload, at least not in this component. What you need is to download the image in a higher level component so that it's available once the user goes offline and gets to this page. Then you can request it normally and the browser's cache should have the image still in memory.

[See this answer on a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48480983/13315676)